# Can't find the ArcGIS License Manager folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, windows-10, arcgis-license-manager

I am using ArcGIS 10.7 for desktop and my operating system is windows 10

I am trying to find out when my ArcGIS license expires, and this expiration date is supposed to be in the ArcGIS License manager folder. I can't find this folder when I am in the ArcGIS folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7

There is just a License folder in the Desktop10.7 folder and it doesn't show the license information

Comment: This information is available in the ArcGIS Administrator app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check on this path:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ArcGIS

Inside that folder look for "ArcGIS Administrator" once you run it, look for "Availability" there you can see the expiration date of your license.